# Google Stackdriver Policy Alert Time Period

Tags: google-stackdriver

I have some uptime checks on instances running only in specific day hours. 
I would like to be able to receive fail alert only in this period.
Anyone know if there is a way to set time period like nagios?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is not possible yet.

However the good news is that there is currently an internal feature request already open for these; but unfortunately, I cannot nor guarantee that this feature will be deployed. Nevertheless, rest assured that product feedback is always seriously taken.

You can subscribe to this feature request for updates, we'll continue to post all future updates in this [links](https://issuetracker.google.com/124777582)